# Refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead. TypeScript: 1 semantic error

Tags: typescript

I receive the following error when compiling my TypeScript file:

```
error TS2686: 'filesize' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

Normally this tells me that I forgot an import, BUT my file already has the necessary import statement:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as fs from 'filesize';

$(function () {
  $('.filesize').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var text = elem.text();
    var niceText = filesize(+text);
    elem.text(niceText);
  });
});
```

What am I still doing wrong? The error is shown in the line where filesize() is called.

Comment: Change the line to `var niceText = fs(+text);` ?

Comment: Oh, *plonk*, missed that. Thanks!